# How to live stream my content to android application?

Tags: android, youtube-api, live-streaming, android-youtube-api

I'm using youtube live to stream my sports event on android mobile application. But it not a viable option because whenever I stop the stream and start a new one, the video code of youtube live stream changes, so I cannot stream again if I stop the current stream. Below is the code for my stream :

```
youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.play();
            youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("video-code");

        }
```

Is there any method to put the new video code automatically using youtube API?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered my question, I'll answer it on my own.

Instead of using youtube API, we can use a `webview`. No instead of using a `video-code` to stream youtube live, we can use `channelID` in the youtube link to permanently embed the live stream to the `webview`.

Here is the code for it:

```
public class WebViewPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_player);

        String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe width=\"400\" height=\"290\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></iframe></body></html>";

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```